# Can I create an activerecord association through an activerecord relation (when using the ancestry gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ancestry

I am using the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) in my rails project to create a hierarchy of groups. A group can belong to a parent group and can have many children groups. Each group can have many users who belong to a group.  The model looks like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry

  has_many :users
end
```

I would love to be able to get all users for the descendants of a group, something like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry

  has_many :users
  has_many :descendants_users, through: :descendants
end
```

which, of course, doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want to get the users of the group then just call group.users? as far as i understood your post, there is no need for the descendents_users

Answer (score 2):

Define a method like this in your Group model.

```
def descendants_users
    User.joins(:groups).where(:group_id => self.subtree_ids) # Use descendant ids if you dont't want 'self' users
end
```

This will perform **1** query to fetch subtree_ids and **1** query to fetch users, and the result is already distinct users set.

Comment: This is a nice answer - it just runs one query.

Comment: In my categories model... i have ***def all_products
    Product.joins(:categories).where(categories:{id:self.subtree_ids})
  end*** and i get duplicates. It's not a distinct set

Answer (score 1):

May be you just should to define method, that returns all of descendants' users. 
So your model could look like this:

```
  class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry

    has_many :users

    def descendants_users
      self.subtree.map(&:users).flatten.compact.uniq
    end
  end
```

Comment: This performs query for each group separately (imagine if there are large no. of groups inside the subtree of self) with iteration(s) later on it to cleanup & remove distinct data. See my answer for optimized way for it..