# How to do a filter and then find Ancestry descendants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack, ancestry

After [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428895/rails-ancestry-get-children-records-of-ancestry-model) (the @thomasfedb answer), I though this would work:

```
@categories = Category.joins(:category_users).where("category_users.user_id = ? AND category_users.interested_learning IS TRUE", current_user.id)
@search = Resource.joins(:categories).where(category_id: @categories.subtree_ids).search_filter(params[:search_filter]).paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page]).search(params[:q])
```

But instead, I receive this error

```
undefined method `subtree_ids' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fce832b1070>
```

I also tried @Rahul answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090848/can-i-create-an-activerecord-association-through-an-activerecord-relation-when)

Without the  Ancestry descendants, it is working like this

```
@search = Resource.joins(:category_users).where("category_users.user_id = ? AND category_users.interested_learning IS TRUE", current_user.id).search_filter(params[:search_filter]).paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page]).search(params[:q])
```

Although I want to do the Ransack search after finding the descendants, the error also appears without Ransack. For this reason, I haven't included it in the title. Without Ransack, it would be like this:

```
@categories = Category.joins(:category_users).where("category_users.user_id = ? AND category_users.interested_learning IS TRUE", current_user.id)
@resources = Resource.joins(:categories).where(category_id: @categories.subtree_ids)
```

I would appreciate any advices on this could work

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a better way to get relevant ids. The original solution I provided will trigger an N+1 query which will become increasingly inefficient the more categories you select. I've also walked through the way to extract those ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@categories.subtree_ids` will not work because `subtree_ids` is an instance method, whereas you're calling on the `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Try this instead:

`@categories.map(&:subtree_ids).flatten.uniq`

This might not be particularly performant, but ancestry stores and parses a column similar to "10/1/3" to manage hierarchy. The above will likely trigger an N+1 query. Another option would be to parse the columns yourself. I'm not sure if ancestry provides a better way to do this, but it's fairly simple:

```
arr = @categories.pluck(:ancestry)
#> ["10/1", "5/6/1", "2", nil, nil]

arr.compact
#> ["10/1", "5/6/1", "2"]

arr.map { |ids| ids.split('/') }
#> [["10","1"],["5","6","1"],["2"]]

arr.flatten
#> ["10","1","5","6","1","2"]

arr.uniq
#> ["10","1","5","6","2"]

arr.map(&:to_i)
#> [10,1,5,6,2]
```

Put it all together (I'd suggest multi-line within a method):

```
@categories.pluck(:ancestry).compact.map { |ids| ids.split('/') }.flatten.uniq.map(&:to_i)
#> [10,1,5,6,2]
```